# No arguments passed to the base constructor. Specify the arguments or mark contract as abstract

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, hardhat, foundry

I'm importing ownable contract from Openzepplin . The contract look like this :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import {Ownable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Test is Ownable{
 
    constructor(){
  
  }

}
```

The Ownable contract from oppenzepplin look like this :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v4.9.0) (access/Ownable.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "../utils/Context.sol";

/**
 * @dev Contract module which provides a basic access control mechanism, where
 * there is an account (an owner) that can be granted exclusive access to
 * specific functions.
 *
 * By default, the owner account will be the one that deploys the contract. This
 * can later be changed with {transferOwnership}.
 *
 * This module is used through inheritance. It will make available the modifier
 * `onlyOwner`, which can be applied to your functions to restrict their use to
 * the owner.
 */
abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
     */
    constructor() {
        _transferOwnership(_msgSender());
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        _checkOwner();
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if the sender is not the owner.
     */
    function _checkOwner() internal view virtual {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Leaves the contract without owner. It will not be possible to call
     * `onlyOwner` functions. Can only be called by the current owner.
     *
     * NOTE: Renouncing ownership will leave the contract without an owner,
     * thereby disabling any functionality that is only available to the owner.
     */
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(address(0));
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Can only be called by the current owner.
     */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Internal function without access restriction.
     */
    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
}
```

You can see there is no contstructor in base contract , still i'm getting error like this `TypeError: No arguments passed to the base constructor. Specify the arguments or mark "Test" as abstract. --> contracts/Test.sol:6:1: | 6 | contract Test is Ownable{ | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines). Note: Base constructor parameters: --> @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:38:16: | 38 |     constructor(address initialOwner) { |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`

What's the problem here ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably importing the newer versions of [openzeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L38) contracts, in which the constructor has an [argument](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/7eba10dd1e4899f5ca93e3ec3a0b3dafff9b1f03/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L38). This has been included to provide felixibilty to the deployer for adding another owner like a safe wallet etc.

If you want the msg.sender to be the address then just pass it in the constructor call.

```
constructor() Ownable(msg.sender) {
  
  }
```